# Executing an arrow function from a constructor in the global context

Tags: javascript, constructor, arrow-functions

```
function Pet(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.getName = () => this.name;
}
const cat = new Pet('Fluffy');

const { getName } = cat;
console.log(getName());
```

In the code above, why does getName prints "Fluffy"? It is executed in the global context. Why does value of *this* still references Pet?

Comment: It doesn’t reference `Pet`. The scope of the arrow function is _inside_ `Pet`, so `this` clearly is taken from that scope. What else do you expect to happen and why?

Comment: If it were a regular function, the value of *this* in this case would be **Window**, hence name would be undefined. Why is it different for the arrow function?

Comment: Is it because arrow function use lexical scoping?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point of arrow functions.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.